# Llamar métodos entre sí y poder visualizar mensajes - Android

Tags: android

Tengo este código y lo que deseo hacer es estar llamando a los dos métodos entre sí, pero necesito poder visualizar los mensajes. Este código lo hace la ejecución, pero no veo los mensajes debido a que nunca se termina de ejecutar el programa. ¿Cómo parar momentáneamente el programa para que se visualicen los mensajes y después reanudar el código? Lo intente con `Thread.sleep` y con `sleep`, pero solo estoy durmiendo el programa y no se visualizan los mensajes.

```
public void monitoreo(){

try{

   estado_comparacion= estado_actual;
   while (comparacion()) {
       ResultSet rs = hilo.ConsultaSql("select * from alumno where id_alumno ='" + ids_alumnos[1] + "'");
       if (rs.next()) {
           estado_comparacion = rs.getString("estado");
       }
   }
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
   public boolean comparacion() {

if (estado_actual.equals(estado_comparacion)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "No hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}else{
    estado_actual = estado_comparacion;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    a=0;
    return  true;
}
```

}

Comment: estas seguro que en algun momento se esta llamando al metodo mensaje1? en mensaje2() llamas al metodo mensaje(), no mensaje1()

Comment: Y por que no hacer eso en un loop? `while(True)`

Comment: ya lo modifique, fue error mio pero el problema en si es que debo hacer que el programa se cicle tal cual, pero también necesito estar visualizando los resultados que en este caso son los mensajes.

Comment: este es el otro   while (comparacion()) {
               ResultSet rs = hilo.ConsultaSql("select * from alumno where id_alumno ='" + ids_alumnos[1] + "'");
               if (rs.next()) {
                   estado_comparacion = rs.getString("estado");
               }
           }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

Comment: public boolean comparacion() {
        if (estado_actual.equals(estado_comparacion)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }else{
            estado_actual = estado_comparacion;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            a=0;
            return  false;
        }
    }

Comment: Hola @AlanDiaz. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! La verdad es difícil leer código puesto en un comentario. Abajo de tu pregunta, hay un enlace para **[edit]** y agregar todo lo que sea necesario. ¿Podrás incluir el código que te parezca pertinente en la pregunta, y no en un comentario?

Comment: Realice otra pregunta esta como:  Android: Detener el ciclo, visualizar el resultado y volver al al ciclo, si fueras tan amable de visualizar allí esta el código, y agradecería si pudieras ayudarme. Gracias por el tiempo.

Comment: Puedes añadir la clase enterera a tu consulta, es decir la activity donde se ejecutan esos metodos, es dificil entender lo que quieres hacer sin el resto del código. ¿Estas llamando a una base de datos ->hilo.ConsultaSql?¿Eso que es?¿ Estas en local, remoto?

Comment: cambio el código para que se pueda leer y va a ser remota y local! Gracias

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es estar consultando una base de datos, pero tiene que ser repetitiva, en otras palabras lo estoy ciclando, para que siempre este consultando, pero como nunca para el código pues no en la pantalla no me da ningún resultado, y lo que quiero esparar el codigo para que puedan aparecer los mensajes que posteriormente los enviare a un text para que se puedan visualizar.