# Android: Detener el ciclo, visualizar el resultado y volver al al ciclo

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente código, como pueden observar estoy ciclando de manera permanente el programa, esto debido a que necesito estar monitoreando los cambios que se presentan, necesito visualizar los Toast que son los mensajes, pero como el programa nunca para no me permite su visualización, intente usar el Thread.sleep y sleep sin tener éxito, necesito detener la ejecución momentánea de este ciclo, realizar la visualización del mensaje y después reanudar el ciclo, alguien sabe como, u otra forma para realizar esto GRACIAS!

```
 public void monitoreo(){

    try{

       estado_comparacion= estado_actual;
       while (comparacion()) {
           ResultSet rs = hilo.ConsultaSql("select * from alumno where id_alumno ='" + ids_alumnos[1] + "'");
           if (rs.next()) {
               estado_comparacion = rs.getString("estado");
           }
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public boolean comparacion() {

    if (estado_actual.equals(estado_comparacion)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }else{
        estado_actual = estado_comparacion;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        a=0;
        return  true;
    }
}
```

Resuelto gracias a: Hictus.

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

public void startTimer() {
    //set a new Timer
    timer = new Timer();
    //initialize the TimerTask's job
    initializeTimerTask();
    //schedule the timer, after the first 5000ms the TimerTask will run every 10000ms
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 2000, 5000); //
}

public void initializeTimerTask() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //get the current timeStamp
                    //show the toast

                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Voy a correr monitoreo espera", duration);
                    toast.show();
                monitoreo();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}


public void monitoreo(){
    try{
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

           ResultSet rs = hilo.ConsultaSql("select * from alumno where id_alumno ='" + ids_alumnos[1] + "'");
           if (rs.next()) {
               estado_comparacion = rs.getString("estado");
           }
        comparacion();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void comparacion() {
                if (estado_actual.equals(estado_comparacion)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    estado_actual = estado_comparacion;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
}
```

Comment: Alan, los Toast son únicamente informativos para ti o planeas tu aplicación los muestre ya estando en producción?

Comment: Si planeo que se muestren en la actividad como observas al final solo sera un resultado, pero no se como hacer que lo muestre, si tienes una idea te agradeciera que la pudieras compartir gracias.

Comment: ya habías hecho esta pregunta aqui o me equivoco? http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35782/llamar-m%c3%a9todos-entre-s%c3%ad-y-poder-visualizar-mensajes-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre utilizar la clase `TimerTask` para generar una tarea que se ejecute cada 2 segundos(es la duración de `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`), de tal manera que se ejecute tu codigo en cada repatición, aquí el codigo.

```
    private Timer mTimer1;
    private TimerTask mTt1;

    private void stopTimer(){
        if(mTimer1 != null){
            mTimer1.cancel();
            mTimer1.purge();
        }
    }

    private void startTimer(){
        mTimer1 = new Timer();
        mTt1 = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                monitoreo();
            }
        };

        mTimer1.schedule(mTt1, 1, 2000);
    }

    public void monitoreo(){

        try{

           estado_comparacion= estado_actual;
           ResultSet rs = hilo.ConsultaSql("select * from alumno where id_alumno ='" + ids_alumnos[1] + "'");
           if (rs.next()) {
              estado_comparacion = rs.getString("estado");
           }

           comparacion();

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public boolean comparacion() {

        if (estado_actual.equals(estado_comparacion)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }else{
            estado_actual = estado_comparacion;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            a=0;
        }
    }
```

Espero te sirvo.

Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias lo voy a intentar!!

Comment: Si me sirvió, muchas gracias!! Me base en tu código e hice lo siguiente lo dejo abajo del código publicado:

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirviera, para eso estamos, si me la marcas como respuesta correcta, eternamente agradecido ;)

Comment: Listo!! Respuesta correcta y muchas gracias de nuevo disculpa que no la allá marcado antes. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Agrega la creación de los `Toast` dentro de [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) para que puedan crearse sin problema:

```
    public boolean comparacion() {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           if (estado_actual.equals(estado_comparacion)){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return true;
           }else{
             estado_actual = estado_comparacion;
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hay cambios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             a=0;
            return  true;
        }

        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: No me soluciono el problema, si queda ciclado pero no me muestra los mensajes. Pero muchas gracias por tu comentario!

Comment: Si creas un Toast al inicio de tu Activity lo muestra? Estoy pensando que tal vez pudieras tener desactivado el mostrar los Toast desde configuración.